# Export Vue dynamic site to Static HTML on run time

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, static-site

I am trying to generate/export the html/css from a Vue Application to a static index.html and the css assets without the script I wrote within the vue app which makes calls to the internal servers.

Use case:

An employee creates a digital Information site about a car of the company.
Here he needs to enter vehiclenumber etc, it then makes a GraphQL query with these parameters to our internal server.
Once the information loaded and is filled in on the site, an option should be given to "Save" (Export) the html/css with only the necessary js for vue components itself to work (e.g. Element vue gallery)
The Employee creates the page using localhost:8080?carnumber=xxx&info=xxx

The Server queries itself should not be included as they will be unreachable from outside the intranet.
So I want the static html to not care about the route and parameters and display the HTML as seen on localhost:8080?carnumber=xxx&info=xxx

I have looked for "static site generators" etc but I have not come across a result I am looking for as the page itself isn't static only the export should be. I also came across Nuxt.js but not exactly how I want it to be, the best would be to have it call like a NuxtGenerateStaticPage(this) function (in my dreams)

Please let me know if anything is unclear.
I appreciate any input/idea :)

Comment: My approach now is going to be to clone the vue app and have one grabbing the data from the data and make it editable for the employee, then exporting it to a car_config.json 

and one app just reading the car_config.json instead of making a server request i think this is good.